# How to solve gimbal lock issue in OpenGL ES iOS 360 player

Tags: ios, matrix, opengl-es, 3d, virtual-reality

I'm using this library to play 360 video:

https://github.com/islate/SlateVideo360

This library and all the other open source libraries that I found have the same issue with the sphere rotation.

After a little investigation I found that all of them suffer from the gimbal lock problem when combining the device motion and the touch.

I read that gimbel lock can be solved by using "Quaternions".

This is my first time with openGL so I don't actually understand how this solve the problem.

I think that the problem is in this lines:

```
- (void)update {
    float aspect = fabs(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(_overture), aspect, 0.1f, 400.0f);
    projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(projectionMatrix, ES_PI, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(modelViewMatrix, 300.0, 300.0, 300.0);
    CMDeviceMotion *d = _motionManager.deviceMotion;
    if (d != nil) {
        CMAttitude *attitude = d.attitude;

        if (_referenceAttitude != nil) {
            [attitude multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:_referenceAttitude];
        } else {
            //NSLog(@"was nil : set new attitude", nil);
            _referenceAttitude = d.attitude;
        }

        float cRoll = -fabs(attitude.roll); // Up/Down en landscape
        float cYaw = attitude.yaw;  // Left/ Right en landscape -> pas besoin de prendre l'opposé
        float cPitch = attitude.pitch; // Depth en landscape -> pas besoin de prendre l'opposé

        UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
        if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight ){
            cPitch = cPitch*-1; // correct depth when in landscape right
        }


        modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateX(modelViewMatrix, cRoll); // Up/Down axis
        modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateY(modelViewMatrix, cPitch);
        modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateZ(modelViewMatrix, cYaw);

        modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateX(modelViewMatrix, ROLL_CORRECTION);

        modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateX(modelViewMatrix, _fingerRotationX);
        modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateY(modelViewMatrix, _fingerRotationY);


    }
    _modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix);
}
```

The x and y touch calculations are in here:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(_isUsingMotion) return;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    float distX = [touch locationInView:touch.view].x - [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view].x;
    float distY = [touch locationInView:touch.view].y - [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view].y;
    distX *= -0.005;
    distY *= -0.005;
    _fingerRotationX += distY *  _overture / 100;
    _fingerRotationY -= distX *  _overture / 100;    

}
```

I Hope that someone can help with that, and fix the problem in all the 360 open source libraries.